# Falla al llamar include

Tags: php, css, bootstrap

Lo que pasa es que tengo una plantilla en dashboard y dividi en dos partes un header y un footer, y las guarde por archivos separados en una que dice plantilla, si llamo esas vistas en un archivo nuevo en blanco solo con include_once me la trae pero solo si ese archivo esta en la raiz si llamo esaa vistas desde otra capeta me las trae pero se pierde el diseño, que sera?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te recomiendo utilizar URL estática para tus estilos y script ejemplo:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

cambialo por :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Dato que el problema que presentas es por esto. si tu llamas desde otra parte buscara ese directorio pero como no esta por ende no cargara los estilos y scripts, en cambio si pones una URL estática llamara directamente esos recursos.

Comment: Perfecto amigo, muchisimas gracias , me funciono ala perfeccion